# Генерация картиночных слоев по координатам для повышения производительности

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть такая ситуация: карта с множеством объектов (максимум 160 тысяч). Для того, чтобы их отрисовать, решил использовать картиночный слой. Благо объекты неактивны, а значит не нужно будет заморачиваться с активными областями и источником данных. Но непонятым для меня остался сам механизм создания этих картиночных слоев.

Что мы имеем:

1) 160 тысяч меток

2) У каждой метки есть координаты

3) Размеры иконки метки - 10х10 (может варьироваться)

Чего нужно добиться:
Итоговый тайл должен представлять собой прозрачное изображение с метками, расположенными в соответствии с их координатами относительно этого тайла.

Пока алгоритм подготовки изображений я представляю примерно так:

1) для каждой метки получить номер тайла

2) получить координаты тайла, отталкиваясь от его номера

3) пропорционально посчитать положение метки относительно тайла (в пикселах)

4) сгруппировать метки внутри тайла и сгенерировать картинку

Есть пара вопросов:

1) насколько правильным является такое решение? может быть, есть более корректные и оптимальные варианты?

2) как правильнее осуществлять расчеты на бэкенде (координаты тайлов, их номера относительно глобальных пиксельных координат). Доступа к api yandex maps на php, как я понимаю, нет, что делать? писать их самому, пользоваться другими библиотеками?

Спасибо!

Comment: А почему не менеджер объектов? https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/

Comment: Вариант с тайлами наиболее оптимальный, т.к. помимо того, что я описал нужно еще перерисовывать картинку метки в зависимости от зума. Нашел примерно ту реализацию, к которой стремлюсь:
https://geo.minsvyaz.ru/#/-1/-1/9/55.87268281534533/37.59687539135742/4
Метка на маленьком зуме имеет форму квадрата, на большом зуме -- имеет форму круга с пропорциональным увеличением.

Comment: Расскажу что сделал: 
1) получил координаты области, охватывающей все метки
2) по координатам получил номера крайних тайлов (нижнего левого и верхнего правого)
3) по этим данным достроил сетку тайлов области
4) по номеру тайла получил координаты, перевел их в другие координаты, а потом эти координаты перевел в глобальные (не нашел возможности напрямую получить глобальные координаты тайла)
По этим данным на стороне сервера будут сгенерированы тайлы. 
Единственная проблема пока -- слишком много ошибок валится в консоль (404, тайл не найден). Буду искать способ их обработать.

Answer (score 1):

У меня было такое. Тоже свои тайлы не всегда загружались. Полагаю тут дело в том, что сервер либо не успевает вовремя обработать запросы сотен тайлов (хотя вряд ли), либо блокируются многочисленные запросы с одного ip. 
Я поступал так: создал одно большое изображение своей карты, без разбивания на тайлы. 
Затем добавил на карту большой прямоугольный полигон с картой в качестве фона. 
Если Ваша область карты достаточно велика, можно ввести свои тайлы. Каждый тайл - свой полигон. Разумеется, можно для разного зума свою карту сделать.

И ещё я бы рекомендовал, сделать кеширование тайлов на сервере (особенно при редком обновлении данных). К чему замедлять работу системы многократно повторяющимися операциями?
Если грамотно прописать заголовки HTTP для тайлов да ещё получить время последнего  обновления данных, можно получить существенный выигрыш по скорости.